# How to to play videos from the web using Opencv and python

Tags: python, html, css, opencv, twebbrowser

am looking devolop something simply with opencv.Am looking to play videos from the web using opencv the way you can play videos from your laptop by passing the location path now a trying to pass the video url and get it to play.so far am getting error any suggestion would be nice.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import urllib3


http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('Get','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWdrO4BoCu8&list=RDNWdrO4BoCu8&start_radio=1')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWdrO4BoCu8&list=RDNWdrO4BoCu8&start_radio=1') 


if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    print("Error opening video file") 


while(cap.isOpened()): 
    

    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if ret == True: 

        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame) 

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
          break
        else: 
            break


cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use pafy to download the video, then use OpenCV to play the video.

```
url = 'https://youtu.be/W1yKqFZ34y4'
vPafy = pafy.new(url)
play = vPafy.getbest(preftype="webm")

#start the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(play.url)
while (True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    """
    your code here
    """
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

resources for installation:

https://pypi.org/project/pafy/

Comment: The question is not asking **how to play video on your pc?** the answer is already available in the [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/). The question asks you to is there any way to play a youtube video?

Comment: @AhmetTavli I apologize, I misread the question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: No problem, no problem for me. just a reminder: `pafy` library is designed for `python2.7`. You can't install it for `python3.7`