# I want to play a video as podcast from YouTube in program without downloading the video from YouTube in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, youtube, pytube

As I said on the title, I want to play a video as podcast from YouTube in program without downloading the video from YouTube in Python. I did a detailed search on the internet on how to do it but I could find nothing about it.

Comment: Seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71376165/how-to-watch-video-without-downloading-like-mpv-using-yt-dl-python).

Comment: No. I want to play the video I have sent to program as podcast. There should not be video. Just its audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [YouTube-DL](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-dl/) we can retrieve the YouTube video audio link then we can provide it to the [VLC media player](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/) to play it without downloading as a file the audio.

```
import youtube_dl, vlc

youtube_dl_options = {
    'quiet': True,
    'format': 'bestaudio',
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as yt_dl:
    info = yt_dl.extract_info(YOUR_VIDEO_ID, download=False)
    audio_url = info['formats'][0]['url']
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(audio_url)
    player.play()
```

[`BaW_jenozKc`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc) is an example of video id.

Comment: I installed the 'vlc' library. But I am getting an error:

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\bugra\Documents\GitHub\x\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Comment: Please consider the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59014318/7123660) then.

Comment: Sir, really thank you a lot. I was searching for how to do this for 8 hours. I was about to go crazy.